# Puzzling Javascript constructor issue

Tags: javascript

A very puzzling problem i am having with JavaScript. look at the code below..

```
az={
   classes:{
      test:function(){
        this.hello=function(name){
          alert('hello '+name);
        }
      }
   },
   getClass:function(name){
    return az.classes[name];
   }
};
var a=new az.classes['test']();
a.hello('foo');
var b= new az.getClass('test')();
b.hello();// fails !!!
```

in the code if you notice we have a class defined inside an object `az.classes`. when try to create an instance of that class by new `az.classes['test]()`, it works and `a.hello()` executes fine. but when i call the method `az.getClass('test')`, which in turn returns the same constructor, but it fails when i say `var b=new az.getClass('test');` here its saying `b` is `undefined`!! and `b.hello()` fails!! i do not understand this behaviour! what is the difference between new `az.classes['test']()` and new `az.getClass('test')`. Are they not the same thing??

Comment: try `var b= new (az.getClass('test'))();` instead. then b will be like a

Comment: @gurvinder372 You must be reading a different question to me. I see `getClass:function(name)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When instantiating a constructor, the first parens indicate what to use at the constructor.

So `new az.classes['test']();` will execute the expression `az.classes['test']` and use the resulting function as the constructor.

Or refactored, it does this:

```
// new az.classes['test']()
//                       ^ expression left of here used as constructor!
var MyConstructor = az.classes['test'];
new MyConstructor();
```

However, `new az.getClass('test')();` executes the expression `az.getClass` which returns your class getter function, and attempts to use that as the constructor. Then your instance tried to be executed with the `()`.

Or refactored, it does this:

```
// new az.getClass('test')();
//                ^ expression left of here used as constructor!
var MyConstructor = az.getClass;
var instance = new MyConstructor('test');
instance(); // obviously not gonna work.
```

See the difference?

You can solve this by wrapping more parens around the expression that should return the constructor:

```
new (az.getClass('test'))();
//                       ^ expression left of here used as constructor!
```

Or by saving the constructor reference to a local variable, and then using it on the next line.  This is probably more sane and readable:

```
var MyConstructor = az.getClass('test');
new MyConstructor();
//               ^ expression left of here used as constructor!
```

Answer (score 3):

A constructor function in JavaScript can return a value, which replaces the value which would normally be returned by the "new" expression.

So `new az.getClass("test")()` will first evaluate `az.getClass("test")` which will return a function.  You are then invoking that function with () which will return undefined since it has no return value.

Comment: +1, the other answer was in fact slightly wrong - operator precedence dictates that `new` is called after `()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with parenthesis (operator precedence). This should work:

```
var b = new (az.getClass('test'))();
```

http://jsbin.com/odajet/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

`var b = new az.getClass('test')();`

is equivalent to first getting the class:

```
var b = new az.classes.getClass('test');
```

b is now the **class** `az.test`, not an instance of it.

and then:

```
b = b();
```

calling the class constructor with the global object as this